# Prove the determinant inequation.

Tags: determinant

Show that $\begin{vmatrix}
a^2 & 2ab & b^2\\ 
ac & ad+bc &bd \\
 c^2& 2cd & d^2
\end{vmatrix}\geq 0$, where $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are real numbers.

Answer (score 3):

I don't buy it. The determinant is equal to $(ad-bc)^3$, from which it follows that if $ad-bc<0$, the assertion is false.

Comment: What if we put b^2 instead of d^2? I tell you this because I saw an exercise like this but with b^2 and I do not know which is good. They can not be both right. But I find it more logical to have d^2 in the right down corner.

Comment: Alex, yes, Goes back, at least, to Fricke and Klein (1897). There is a typo in Magnus (Noneuclidean Tesselations) on page 23, precisely where they give the incorrect exponent for $(ad-bc).$

Comment: put in a short answer. Looked through F+K, they don't bother ever stating the determinant.

Answer (score 0):

this is Important for fuchsian groups.

$$
H =
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
0 &  0 & -1 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Given
$$
Q =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\alpha^2 &  2 \alpha \beta & \beta^2 \\
\alpha \gamma & \alpha \delta + \beta \gamma & \beta \delta \\
\gamma^2 & 2 \gamma \delta & \delta^2
\end{array}
\right),
$$
there is a typographical error on  page 23 of Magnus (Noneuclidean Tesselations and Their Groups), actually $\det Q = (\alpha \delta - \beta \gamma)^3.$
We have the identity
$$  Q^T H Q = (\alpha \delta - \beta \gamma)^2 H. $$